# HTML5 iPhone app wanting html ad network

Tags: html, cordova, ads

Hi I am wondering if there is a ad network that works with html5 / cordova, I use to be able to use the javascript version of admob, but no more. It seems that Google us shut that part down.

I am wondering if someone knows any other ad networks that are really good with html5 apps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob). It is an admob plugin compatible with iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mopub](http://www.mopub.com/) with pure JS and HTML.

But, I would consider just using the original native SDK of [AdMob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/), its really easy and involves about 3 lines of native code. the minus is that you don't have the option to use it with Phonegap Build.